# AJAX validation not working(Submit button enabling/disabling)

Tags: php, ajax, validation

My ajax form has 4 fields.

The condition is as follows:

Initially,the `submit` button is disabled.

After entering a valid,unregistered email-id and a valid mobile number this `submit` button should get enabled.

But even if I enter a registered email-id and valid mobile number button is getting enabled but actually it should be disabled as the entered email-id is already exist in database.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Code snippet:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                pic1 = new Image(16, 16); 
                pic1.src = "loader.gif";

                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $("#email").change(function()
                    { 
                        var eml = $("#email").val();
                        $("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
                            $.ajax({  
                                        type: "POST",  
                                        url: "echeck.php",  
                                        data: "email="+ eml,  
                                        success: function(msg)
                                        {
                                            $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                                            {
                                                if(msg == 'Not Exists')
                                                { 
                                                    $("#email").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#email").addClass("object_ok");
                                                    $(this).html('&nbsp;');
                                                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                                                }  
                                                else  
                                                {  
                                                    $("#email").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#email").addClass("object_error");
                                                    $(this).html(msg);
                                                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                            }); 
                    });

                    $("#mobile").change(function()
                    { 
                        var mbe = $("#mobile").val();
                        if(mbe.length >= 10)
                        {
                            $("#mstatus").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
                            $.ajax({  
                                        type: "POST",  
                                        url: "mcheck.php",  
                                        data: "mobile="+ mbe,  
                                        success: function(msg)
                                        {
                                            $("#mstatus").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                                            {
                                                if(msg == 'OK')
                                                { 
                                                    $("#mobile").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#mobile").addClass("object_ok");
                                                    $(this).html('&nbsp;');
                                                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                                                }  
                                                else  
                                                {  
                                                    $("#mobile").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#mobile").addClass("object_error");
                                                    $(this).html(msg);
                                                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#mstatus").html('<font color="red">The Mobile should have at least <strong>10</strong> characters.</font>');
                            $("#mobile").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                            $("#mobile").addClass("object_error");
                            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }   
                    });

                    $("#proposedby").change(function()
                    { 
                        var pisa = $("#proposedby").val();
                        if(pisa.length >= 4)
                        {
                            $("#proposedby_status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
                            $.ajax({  
                                        type: "POST",  
                                        url: "pcheck.php",  
                                        data: "proposedby="+ pisa,  
                                        success: function(msg)
                                        {
                                            $("#proposedby_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                                            {
                                                if(msg == 'OK')
                                                { 
                                                    $("#proposedby").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#proposedby").addClass("object_ok");
                                                    $(this).html('&nbsp;');
                                                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                                                }  
                                                else  
                                                {  
                                                    $("#proposedby").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#proposedby").addClass("object_error");
                                                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                                    $(this).html(msg);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#proposedby_status").html('<font color="red">The Proposed by ISA No should have at least <strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
                            $("#proposedby").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                            $("#proposedby").addClass("object_error");
                            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }
                    });

                    $("#secondedby").change(function()
                    { 
                        var sisa = $("#secondedby").val();
                        if(sisa.length >= 4)
                        {
                            $("#secondedby_status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
                            $.ajax({  
                                        type: "POST",  
                                        url: "scheck.php",  
                                        data: "secondedby="+ sisa,  
                                        success: function(msg)
                                        {
                                            $("#secondedby_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                                            {
                                                if(msg == 'OK')
                                                { 
                                                    $("#secondedby").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#secondedby").addClass("object_ok");
                                                    $(this).html('&nbsp;');
                                                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                                                }  
                                                else  
                                                {  
                                                    $("#secondedby").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#secondedby").addClass("object_error");
                                                    $(this).html(msg);
                                                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#secondedby_status").html('<font color="red">The Seconded by ISA No should have at least <strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
                            $("#secondedby").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                            $("#secondedby").addClass("object_error");
                            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }   
                    });
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                });
            -->
        </script>


 <center>

<div align="center">
<h2 align="center">AJAX Username Verification</h2>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <table width="700" border="0">  
    <tr>
      <td width="200"><div align="right">Email-Id:&nbsp;</div></td>
      <td width="100"><input type="email" id="email" name="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-\_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-\_.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,3}$" /></td>
      <td width="400" align="left"><div id="status"></div></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td width="200"><div align="right">Mobile:&nbsp;</div></td>
      <td width="100"><input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" pattern="^[0-9-]+" maxlength="10"  /></td>
      <td width="400" align="left"><div id="mstatus"></div></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td width="200"><div align="right">Proposed By (Isa no):&nbsp;</div></td>
      <td width="100"><input type="text" name="proposedby" id="proposedby" /></td>
      <td width="400" align="left"><div id="proposedby_status"></div></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td width="200"><div align="right">Seconded By (Isa no):&nbsp;</div></td>
      <td width="100"><input type="text" name="secondedby" id="secondedby" /></td>
      <td width="400" align="left"><div id="secondedby_status"></div></td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

</div>
 </center>
```

Comment: firstly change `data: "email="+ eml` to `data: {email : eml`}

Comment: and i think instead of making `enable` and `disable` button's `hide` and `show` would be a gr8

Comment: Thank you..let me try this

Comment: You need to update the AJAX and your PHP to check all fields each time something changes, or a flag that stores whether each input is in a valid state or not. At the moment, you validate the email, it returns that it exists, the button remains disabled. But then you put mobile in, the mobile number is fine, so it enables the button because you haven't checked the rest of the form is now okay.

Comment: $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled'); you remove attribute in every success response

Comment: use flags for every response true then remove $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');  using this otherwise submitt is disabled

Comment: if(msg == 'Not Exists')
                                                { 
                                                    $("#email").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#email").addClass("object_ok");
                                                    $(this).html('&nbsp;');
                                                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');// this should not done their
var flag=true //set flag their 
                                                }

Comment: I've tried all the suggestion given..But nothing works out. @JunaidAhmed I've used the condition `if flag is true then disable the button` ..But no change..

Comment: you have to use flag for ever true response

Comment: @JunaidAhmed.Done.But not working..Added if conditions 

`if(flag == true && flag1 == true)
{
$('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
}` 

 after both email and mobile conditions.

Comment: what it is giving to you

Comment: check variable should global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                pic1 = new Image(16, 16); 
                pic1.src = "loader.gif";

                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    var flagemail=false;
                    var flagemobile=false;
                    var flagepropesed=false;
                    var flagesecondby=false;

                    $("#email").change(function()
                    { 
                        var eml = $("#email").val();
                        $("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
                            $.ajax({  
                                        type: "POST",  
                                        url: "echeck.php",  
                                        data: "email="+ eml,  
                                        success: function(msg)
                                        {
                                            $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                                            {
                                                if(msg == 'Not Exists')
                                                { 
                                                    $("#email").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#email").addClass("object_ok");
                                                    $(this).html('&nbsp;');
                                                   flagemail=true;
                                                }  
                                                else  
                                                {  
                                                    $("#email").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#email").addClass("object_error");
                                                    $(this).html(msg);
                                                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                            }); 
                    });

                    $("#mobile").change(function()
                    { 
                        var mbe = $("#mobile").val();
                        if(mbe.length >= 10)
                        {
                            $("#mstatus").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
                            $.ajax({  
                                        type: "POST",  
                                        url: "mcheck.php",  
                                        data: "mobile="+ mbe,  
                                        success: function(msg)
                                        {
                                            $("#mstatus").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                                            {
                                                if(msg == 'OK')
                                                { 
                                                    $("#mobile").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#mobile").addClass("object_ok");
                                                    $(this).html('&nbsp;');
                                                    flagemobile=true;
                                                }  
                                                else  
                                                {  
                                                    $("#mobile").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#mobile").addClass("object_error");
                                                    $(this).html(msg);
                                                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#mstatus").html('<font color="red">The Mobile should have at least <strong>10</strong> characters.</font>');
                            $("#mobile").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                            $("#mobile").addClass("object_error");
                            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }   
                    });

                    $("#proposedby").change(function()
                    { 
                        var pisa = $("#proposedby").val();
                        if(pisa.length >= 4)
                        {
                            $("#proposedby_status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
                            $.ajax({  
                                        type: "POST",  
                                        url: "pcheck.php",  
                                        data: "proposedby="+ pisa,  
                                        success: function(msg)
                                        {
                                            $("#proposedby_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                                            {
                                                if(msg == 'OK')
                                                { 
                                                    $("#proposedby").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#proposedby").addClass("object_ok");
                                                    $(this).html('&nbsp;');
                                                    flagepropesed=true;
                                                }  
                                                else  
                                                {  
                                                    $("#proposedby").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#proposedby").addClass("object_error");
                                                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                                    $(this).html(msg);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#proposedby_status").html('<font color="red">The Proposed by ISA No should have at least <strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
                            $("#proposedby").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                            $("#proposedby").addClass("object_error");
                            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }
                    });

                    $("#secondedby").change(function()
                    { 
                        var sisa = $("#secondedby").val();
                        if(sisa.length >= 4)
                        {
                            $("#secondedby_status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
                            $.ajax({  
                                        type: "POST",  
                                        url: "scheck.php",  
                                        data: "secondedby="+ sisa,  
                                        success: function(msg)
                                        {
                                            $("#secondedby_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                                            {
                                                if(msg == 'OK')
                                                { 
                                                    $("#secondedby").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#secondedby").addClass("object_ok");
                                                    $(this).html('&nbsp;');
                                                    flagesecondby=true;
                                                }  
                                                else  
                                                {  
                                                    $("#secondedby").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                                                    $("#secondedby").addClass("object_error");
                                                    $(this).html(msg);
                                                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#secondedby_status").html('<font color="red">The Seconded by ISA No should have at least <strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
                            $("#secondedby").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                            $("#secondedby").addClass("object_error");
                            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }   
                    });
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                   // Check This If all Flags are true then remove
                    if(flagemail==true && flagemobile==true && flagepropesed==true && flagesecondby == true)
                    {
                         $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                });
            -->
        </script>


 <center>

<div align="center">
<h2 align="center">AJAX Username Verification</h2>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <table width="700" border="0">  
    <tr>
      <td width="200"><div align="right">Email-Id:&nbsp;</div></td>
      <td width="100"><input type="email" id="email" name="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-\_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-\_.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,3}$" /></td>
      <td width="400" align="left"><div id="status"></div></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td width="200"><div align="right">Mobile:&nbsp;</div></td>
      <td width="100"><input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" pattern="^[0-9-]+" maxlength="10"  /></td>
      <td width="400" align="left"><div id="mstatus"></div></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td width="200"><div align="right">Proposed By (Isa no):&nbsp;</div></td>
      <td width="100"><input type="text" name="proposedby" id="proposedby" /></td>
      <td width="400" align="left"><div id="proposedby_status"></div></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td width="200"><div align="right">Seconded By (Isa no):&nbsp;</div></td>
      <td width="100"><input type="text" name="secondedby" id="secondedby" /></td>
      <td width="400" align="left"><div id="secondedby_status"></div></td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

</div>
 </center>
```

try this it may help you

Comment: I've implemented this.In line 170 the condition is not set to true whereas the values of flagemail,flagemobile,flagepropesed,flagesecondby are set to true in line 32,65,106 & 147 respectively.I've cross-checked it by giving alert's.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wsoaof4r/3/   check this it enable when all are fields are filled other wise make it disable again